# Record videoconference application to flv

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, wowza, video-conferencing

I've spent plenty of time solving this problem, but it looks like I need some help. I have a [web conference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_conferencing) application which provides ability to stream live video, chat, share documents, draw on a whiteboard, share desktop, etc. And now I want to record everything that happens in taken separately so called *webinar*, including video and sound. So I'm looking for tools that can help with this goal.

Here's input data:

- This is Adobe Flash based application
- Using [wowza server](http://www.wowza.com/)
- Everything should be recorded on server
- Many webinars can be in recording mode at the same time
- Record should be represented in video (flv, mp4 or whatever)

What I've done so far and what I problems I have:

I have implemented recording on server side. But this is not a video, this is just a list of commands to recreate passed webinar. It works, but has lot's of limitations and problems with rewinding.
And now I'm testing [this](https://github.com/zeropointnine/leelib/tree/master/src/leelib/util/flvEncoder) FLV Encoding library. I created AIR application that starts on server when record is needed, connects to taken webinar and takes screenshots from itself with [BitmapData.draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) method. Works pretty neat, but has some limitation that I'm looking help with:

1. First of all, this is sound problem. I have no idea how to catch all
   sounds from all sources in flash. So far from my tests and googling I conclude that [SoundMixer.computeSpectrum()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum%28%29) won't help me to do this. Maybe this can be done on server side by mixing all streams on the right time but I think this can lead to synchronization problems and I prefer to capture sound on client. **Maybe there is way to capture audio byte array from rtmp stream somehow?**
2. Security problems. We have 2 kinds of them. First ones are with streaming videos. BitmapData.draw() method throws exeptions even after adding `<StreamAudioSampleAccess>true</StreamAudioSampleAccess>
   <StreamVideoSampleAccess>true</StreamVideoSampleAccess>` on server. There are lots of  posts about this problem and no good solution.
   But more complex problem is that YouTube videos can be opened in webinar using api player. And in this situation I have no idea how to resolve security problem. **Maybe someone knows a way or workaround to use BitmapData.draw() on YouTube AS3 player?**

**Or maybe there is another good way to solve my recording issue?**

Comment: Is this a web based application?  We've solved this problem using Flash Media Live Encoder, but that requires access to the user's desktop.

Comment: Web conference itself is web based, but I can't record webinar on client's machine. Well, I can actually, but I think I'll do it only as  a last choice. On server I can run almost anything. Does Flash Media Live Encoder have ability to record only flash or air app sound and screen to video in case of several different this kind apps running at same time? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, I only have experience with recording the entire desktop.  FMLE is really only the encoder/transmitter and there are drivers that are doing the actual capturing of the video and audio, so I suppose it's possible that there could be a driver that would do that but I have no personal knowledge of it.

Answer (score 0):

Free Apache Openmeetings conferencing [1] has a java recording application inside which should work in 3.0 release. Just use it.

[1] http://openmeetings.apache.org/